# Is there an equivalent for dateutil relativedelta(weekday=FR) but for MONTHS?

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I would like to parse dates in a script and I was wondering if there is an equivalent of the:

```
relativedelta(days=1, weekday=MO)
```

but for months?

For now, I extract the month number in my text and compare it to the document's creation date (and month). However, this is quite long and repetitive (and I have to do it for future tenses, present tenses and past tenses)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `relativedelta(month=2)` to a `datetime` object will give you the same date and time, except in February. If this creates a non-existent date, the date will be truncated at the last existing date, e.g.:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

print(datetime(2015, 3, 30) + relativedelta(month=2))   # 2015-02-28 00:00:00
```

As explained in the [relativedelta documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html):

> year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond:
>
> Absolute information (argument is singular); adding or subtracting a
>       relativedelta with absolute information does not perform an aritmetic
>       operation, but rather REPLACES the corresponding value in the
>       original datetime with the value(s) in relativedelta.

All the "singular" arguments are processed as "set this component of the thing I'm being added to/subtracted from to this value", whereas the plural versions of the same arguments say "Add/subtract this number to/from this component".

Note that the relativedelta documentation also lays out the order that each component is applied, but suffice to say that absolute values are applied *before* relative values, so `relativedelta(month=3, months=2)` will set the month to March, then add 2 months (so, basically, it's equivalent to `relativedelta(month=5)`).

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `weekday = MO` (or `weekday = calendar.MONDAY`) can be `month = 1` for January, `month = 2` for February, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

These operations are handled most gracefully by the Python `arrow` library. Datetime objects can be converted to Arrow objects and vice versus if you need to continue using `datetime`, i.e. for compatibility with other modules.